# Запуск shell-скрипта через alt+f2

Tags: linux, shell

Имеется скрипт для запуска приложения

```
#!/bin/bash
wine /opt/winbox.exe
```

который размещается по пути, где лежат прочие скрипты

```
/home/myuser/scripts/winbox.sh
```

Для него я создаю символическую ссылку

```
sudo ln -s /home/myuser/scripts/winbox.sh /usr/local/bin/winbox
```

но при попытке запуска через

```
alt+f2 --> winbox
```

выдает ошибку

```
Error when getting information for file '/home/myuser/winbox': No such file or directory
```

где я допускаю ошибку и как правильно запустить скрипт через alt+f2?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно кому-то пригодится последовательность действий, хотя причина была только в моей невнимательности.

1. Создаем скрипт. В моем случае он указан в вопросе.
2. Даем права на выполнение:

   ```
   sudo chmod u+x /home/myuser/scripts/winbox.sh
   ```
3. Создаем символическую ссылку в каталоге /usr/bin/ или /usr/local/bin

   ```
   sudo ln -s /home/myuser/scripts/winbox.sh /usr/bin/winbox
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Найди 10 отличий:

```
/home/myuser/scripts/winbox.sh
```

и

```
/home/myuser/winbox
```

Почему у тебя в ошибке нет куска пути `scripts`?

UPD: В каментах выяснилось, что не было добавлено бита исполнения через `chmod +x script.sh`

Comment: Оценил сарказм. Ошибки читать умею. Поэтому и хочу спросить, как так? Симлинк создаю с указанием полного пути (который включает scripts), а ошибка указывает каталог пользователя

Comment: Симлинк ссылается на файл корректно: lrwxrwxrwx 1 root staff 27 Aug 19 19:11 /usr/local/bin/winbox -> /home/myuser/scripts/winbox.sh

Comment: Попробуй переместить скрипт на уровень вверх (в /home/myuser/) и пересоздай симлинк. Чё-нить поменяется?

Comment: Разобрался! Я забыл дать скрипту разрешение на выполнение: sudo chmod u+x /home/myuser/scripts/winbox.sh

Comment: Дополнил ответ.